# The elements in the composite field $FK$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Where $F$,$K$ are two fields. What does the element in the composite field $FK$ look like? All the elements are generated by the elements of $F$ and $K$? (combination of the elements of $F$ and $K$) I think $FK$ is pretty close to the free product of $F$ and $K$; is $FK \subsetneq F*K$? Thank you!

Comment: You cannot define the compositum $FK$ without embedding $F,K$ into a larger field $L$. The isomorphism type of $FK$ may depend on the embeddings $F \hookrightarrow L \hookleftarrow K$! The term "free product" doesn't make sense here. I suggest that you google "compositum of fields" (or look it up in an algebra textbook) and then make your question more specific.

Comment: @Martin Brandenburg, thank you,but in Galois theory,there is such a theorem: if G,H are Galois over field F, then GH is also Galois over F, however here we don't define any embedding.

Comment: @Joseph: No, the embedding into a common larger field is necessary. Any accurate statement of that theorem will include it - go look at whatever textbook or source you consider reputable.

Comment: @ZevChonoles Sorry, I use Dummit's textbook, if you check proposition 21 in section 14.4, you can find it doesn't say anything about the embedding.

Comment: @Joseph: Look at the **definition of composite field** on p.528. Look at every occurrence of a composite field from p.528 until p.545 - they all require that the fields be subfields of some common, larger field. Then, on p.545, the authors remark that algebraic extensions of a field $F$ can always be seen as subfields of a given algebraic closure $\overline{F}$, so that composites can be taken with $\overline{F}$ as the **implicit** larger field being used. From then on, any composite field in Dummit and Foote uses this convention.

Comment: @Joseph: Therefore, when we get to your proposition on p.592, even though it doesn't **explicitly** say to assume $K_1$ and $K_2$ are both subfields of some common larger field, **by the authors' own statement of convention** the common larger field being used is some fixed algebraic closure $\overline{F}$.

Comment: @ZevChonoles Thank you very much!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To answer your question on what $FK$ looks like, under the assumption that they both sit inside an (unspecified) immense field $\Omega$, let me point out that $FK$ may be thought of in three ways: $F(K)$, $K(F)$, and the intersection of all subfields of $\Omega$ that contain $F$ and $K$.

If $S$ is *any* subset of $\Omega$, the set $F(S)$ can be defined as the set of all $F$-rational expressions in finitely many elements of $S$. A moment’s thought convinces you that $F(S)$ is indeed a field, and a few more moments will convince you that this field is also the intersection of all subfields of $\Omega$ containing both $F$ and $S$. This shows you that the “three ways” I mention at the top do indeed describe the same field, and further describe what elements of $FK$ look like.